# Slow data retrieval from Spark Cache VS Database

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have introduced Spark Cache to manipulate data in memory in our product, because working with remote databases aggressively where data size is Huge (BIG DATA) was too time consuming.

Right now we have noticed that once the data is loaded into spark responds even more slower then directly querying the original source(remote database)

We are using sparkSQL to retrieve Data, and same Query returns way earlier from remote DB with Data where as Spark cache with single node on same Computer lags behind big time.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Sample Query with Spark UI Snapshots:

```
SELECT column1, SUM(column2) FROM tableName WHERE column2 > 200 GROUP BY column1 ORDER BY column1
```

Data **100% loaded** in Spark in-memory. [See Image](http://s6.postimg.org/ychwdth01/Screenshot_2015_07_03_12_47_01.png)

It took upto **15 minutes** to load results from Spark. [See Image](http://s6.postimg.org/e82kwy89d/Screenshot_2015_07_03_12_46_43.png)


 Where Spark Cache contains around **50,000 records**. And the Machine on which the query tested have **16 CPU cores** with **64GB memory**.

My Question is 50,000 records are nothing, why it is taking so many minutes instead of fraction of milli-seconds. Where every thing is done on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

First off, check if the dataset is cached 100% (for example in Spark UI). If not, Spark has to fetch some data remotely or from disk and combine it with in-memory data.

Secondly, Spark is probably not as fast as a dedicated database, so transferring a result from a very fast database over the network might simply be faster than letting a general-purpose engine compute the result, especially if the database runs on a single machine.

Comment: i have updated the original post and added more explanation (with screen shots), so if you have time to read ...  please have a look... any guidance will be appreciated...

Comment: Do you cache the result of your SQL query, or just the loaded data? Can you try the query without ORDER BY?

Comment: **First**, data is already cached and it is not being cached again(query results) because i might not use those results again.
**Second**, i did removed "ORDER BY" from query, then the time to calculate jobs reduced up to 2 minutes resulting the job done in 12 minutes which is still tooo slow if we compare it to normal database data retrieval...

Comment: Also as i see in Spark-UI, number of partitions are 128, does that mean every select query is executed on each partition then the union is taken which is slowing down all data retrieval ?